# Equivalent of Oracle DECODE function in C#

Tags: c#

DECODE built in function in Oracle

```
decode( expression , search , result [, search , result]... [, default] )
```

http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/decode.php

Want the similar functionality in C# language. Any built in method ?

I know i can use if else if structure or switch but then i need to do it dynamically.Please share some logical steps for creating one if not there.

Thank you for your precious time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An old question, but since it got pulled out of obscurity by another answer, here is how I would try to replicate the `decode` function in `C#`. Not exactly the same, but not too bad either:

```
public static TOutput Decode<TInput, TOutput>(TInput expression, params Tuple<TInput, TOutput>[] searchResultPairs)
    => DecodeWithDefault(expression, default(TOutput), searchResultPairs);

public static TOutput DecodeWithDefault<TInput, TOutput>(TInput expression, TOutput defaultValue, params Tuple<TInput, TOutput>[] searchResultPairs)
{
    foreach(var searchResultPair in searchResultPairs)
    {
        if ((expression == null && searchResultPair.Item1 == null)
            || (expression != null && expression.Equals(searchResultPair.Item1)))
        {
            return searchResultPair.Item2;
        }
    }

    return defaultValue;
}
```

Sample usage:

```
Console.WriteLine(Decode(5, Tuple.Create(23, "twenty-three"), Tuple.Create(5, "five")));
Console.WriteLine(Decode(23, Tuple.Create(23, "twenty-three"), Tuple.Create(5, "five")));
Console.WriteLine(Decode(6, Tuple.Create(23, "twenty-three"), Tuple.Create(5, "five")));
Console.WriteLine(DecodeWithDefault(6, "not found", Tuple.Create(23, "twenty-three"), Tuple.Create(5, "five")));
```

Output:

> five
>   twenty-three
>
> not found

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for a `Dictionary<int, string>`.